# Regex - match an optionally repeated pattern of capture groups

Tags: php, regex, parsing, regex-group

Appologies for not knowing exactly how to word this question. There is probably even a better title. I'm open to suggestions.

I have the following subjects:

```
(Field1 = 'Value1') and (Field2 = 'Value2')
```

and

```
(Field1 = 'Value1') and (Field2 = 'Value2') or (Field3 = 'Value3')
```

I want to match in such a way that I have each thing between the () in groups and each conjunction in a group. So, for the second one, some variation of

```
0: Field1 = 'Value1'
1: and
2: Field2 = 'Value2'
3: or
4: Field3 = 'Value3'
```

The good news is, I've got regex that works on the first:

```regex
\(([A-Za-z0-9\s\'=]+)\) (and|or) \(([A-Za-z0-9\s\'=]+)\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/hMXAXS/1

But (on the second subject) it doesn't match the third "and ()". I need to support arbitrary numbers of groups. I can modify it to just look for "and ()" but then it doesn't match the first group.

How can I tell regex to do this? I either need to "double count" some groups (which is fine) or have some other way of optionally looking for additional patterns and matching them.

Thanks for the help!

PS: I was able to get my application to work with the regex `((and|or) \(([A-Za-z0-9\s\'=]+)\))+` and then just accepting that the first group would never match and creating application logic to support this. Still, I'd bet there's a better way.

Comment: Are you parsing the WHERE clause of a MySQL query?  Might you encounter nested parentheticals? Might a value contain a closing parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are OK with getting three groups per match...

1 = key
2 = value
3 = conjunction verb

Then this regex will also allow parenthesis in the value.

```regex
/\((.*?) = '(.*?)'\) ?(and|or)?/gm
```

Which results in these matches for this string...

`(Field1 = 'Value1') and (Field2 = '(in parenthesis)') and (Field3 = 'Value3')`

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This was a bit closer to what I needed.

This is the regex I ended up using for my specific case, since I didn't actually need to capture keys/values.

https://regex101.com/r/1BvgWf/1

Comment: The `m` pattern modifier has no effect on the pattern and should be removed.  This answer does not collect the matched values in the structure demanded in the question body.

Comment: The flags are taken directly from the original example link. I did not modify them at all. I think trying to be helpful is more important than trying to be a robot, so offering a few options for how the OP can address the problem is not a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `preg_match_all` here with the regex pattern `(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))|(?:and|or)` as follows:

```php
$input = "(Field1 = 'Value1') and (Field2 = 'Value2') or (Field3 = 'Value3')";
preg_match_all("/(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))|(?:and|or)/", $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Field1 = 'Value1'
    [1] => and
    [2] => Field2 = 'Value2'
    [3] => or
    [4] => Field3 = 'Value3'
)
```

Comment: @Apollo what if a value contains a closing parenthesis? https://3v4l.org/H1VYi

Comment: I ran into that problem, and have decided that a rule that the value does not contain any parentheses is valid for this job. I opted to allow for brackets [ in the values, but not parentheses.

Comment: Really great answer. Another answer was a little closer to what I needed, and I ended up using it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not worried about fringe cases where delimiting words or paretheses can exist within the parenthetical expressions, then `preg_split()` generates the desired flat array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gIEND))

```
$input = "(Field1 = 'Val and ue1') and (Field2 = 'Valu or e2') or (Field3 = 'Value3')";
var_export(
    preg_split(
        "~^\(|\)$|\) (and|or) \(~",
        $input,
        0,
        PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY|PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
    )
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'Field1 = \'Val and ue1\'',
  1 => 'and',
  2 => 'Field2 = \'Valu or e2\'',
  3 => 'or',
  4 => 'Field3 = \'Value3\'',
)
```

Or simplify the pattern by pre-trimming the outermost parentheses. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PHDig))

```
var_export(preg_split("~\) (and|or) \(~", trim($input, '()'), 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
```

---

You can also use the continue metacharacter `\G` to continue matching from the end of the previous match: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eJbcc))  This takes [88 steps](https://regex101.com/r/25XsNd/1) versus Tim's pattern which takes 280 steps to parse the string.

```
$input = "(Field1 = 'Val and ue1') and (Field2 = 'Valu or e2') or (Field3 = 'Value3')";
preg_match_all('~(?:^\(|\G(?!^)(?:\) | \())\K(?:(?:and|or)|[^)]+)~', $input, $m);
print_r($m[0]);
```

---

Edit after the asker accepted an answer that does not provide the output array structure stated in the question: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UEmn0))

```
preg_match_all("~\((\S+ = '.*?')\) ?(or|and)?~", $input, $m, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($m);
```

This does not check that a parenthetical expression occurs after a conjunction.  Also, when iterating the matches an extra check will be required to see if the third group (`[2]`) is declared.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => (Field1 = 'Val and ue1') and
            [1] => Field1 = 'Val and ue1'
            [2] => and
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => (Field2 = 'Valu or e2') or
            [1] => Field2 = 'Valu or e2'
            [2] => or
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => (Field3 = 'Value3')
            [1] => Field3 = 'Value3'
        )
)
```